# How to limit access permission to only one spreadsheet instead of access to all spreadsheets from user app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to build a web app based on Google services i.e. Gmail, Sheets, Calendar, Drive, which uses the spreadsheet as sort of a database.

The web UI should be accessible only to the employees in the current company and should not have access to the script itself, but still be able to write to the spreadsheet. I know that technically I could build the same thing faster and better on a server using Google's API's for those services but the company requires that the web app will be based on the spreadsheet they're currently using so they still could view it at any time.

The problem is that I don't want them to have access to the script itself so they can't edit or delete it by mistake, and to remove the usage of the app when they stop paying.

This is how I attend it:

1. The company shares the spreadsheet with me and gives me edit rights.
2. I create an apps-script project then convert it to standard Google Cloud Project and connect it with the spreadsheet that was shared with me.
3. Deploying the web app and "Execute it as user accessing the web app".

I link to the specific spreadsheet using `SpreadsheetApp.openById`, but Google warns the user during the access authorization that the app has access to all spreadsheets of the user and can add create and delete them, something that I'm not happy with, and I guess the company as well.

I've even tried to make myself owner of a spreadsheet and share it with others so they won't need to write on their own Drive which didn't work either.

Is there any way to restrict access permission to only one spreadsheet by the app?

I need to handle some kind of user activity which means that I can see who is finishing tasks and who will get new ones, and write that data to the sheet. Will I be able to do it when "Executing the script as ME(owner)"?

Comment: `even tried to make myself owner of a Spreadsheet and share it with others so they won't need to write on their own Drive which didn't work either.` Explain.

Comment: For example, how about using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` at the manifest file of `appsscrit.json`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3) By this, users can access to only the file which is created by the scope. For this situation, how about the following flow? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: 1. Set the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to the manifest file to the project which deployed Web Apps. At this time, of course, when there are other required scopes, please add them. 2. Create new Spreadsheet using the script in this project. The script uses the scope. By this, the script can access to only the created Spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheMaster - I meant that i created the needed Spreadsheet for the project and shared it with the users thought maybe this way they i won't need special permissions from them, i guess it won't work because the file will be linked also in their drive therefor need the permission.

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks. so if i understand correctly I'm creating a Spreadsheet from the code? and this way i'll still need to share the sheet with the users or they will automatically have access to it? also are they going to be able to view and edit the script - which I'm trying to hide from users? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Michael `it won't work because the file will be linked also in their drive therefor need the permission.`  Why would the file be linked? Don't provide access to the spreadsheet to them. Execute as "Me" and access: "Anyone even anonymous" should be enough.

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for the input! but isn't there a risk letting people execute the script as me? also will i still be able to check which user is accessing the script i need it for user record to write who did what task. and last - this way again they won't have access to the spreadsheet which they demand to retain.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. In your situation, when `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is used, as one important point, please use Drive API and Sheets API which are not Drive Service and Spreadsheet Service. In this case, you can use Advanced Google Services. By this, the script can be prepared with only one scope. And the script can access to only the files which were created by the script in the project. Of course, the created Spreadsheet can be shared with users using the script if you want to make users edit the Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks a lot for the info! so if i understand correct the way I approach it is as foloows - First open a standalone app-scripts project with it create a Spreadsheet then interact with it using the according API inside the script? will i be able to share the Sheet using the script or do i need to share it manually? also this way they won't be able to access my script which is my highest concern right now?

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. A for Q1: Yes. A for Q2: You can share the Spreadsheet with both the script and manual. A for Q3: If the standalone script deployed the Web Apps as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`, the script is not shown for users. `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`, the script is required to be shared with users. In this case, users can see the script. But users cannot edit the script. You can see about Web Apps at https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Comment: @Tanaike thank you very much for the detailed answers and your patience! seems very complicated I will take a look at your Guide which seems to be very helpful and detailed, hope that will give me a better understanding. thanks a lotfor all yor help!

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer and accept it? I think that your question and answer will be useful for other users.

Comment: @Tanaike sure thing, once I've tested that this solution works for me.